# How can I add Pascal Syntax Coloring to Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5, pascal, freepascal, delphi, text-coloring

I am trying to get Syntax Coloring for Pascal (or Object Pascal or FreePascal) in Xcode 5.  I have tried using the package provided here:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Jul/msg00082.html

I added the file "Pascal.xclangspec" to:
/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/

This didn't appear to do anything after closing and reopening Xcode (i.e. clicking on Editor > Syntax Coloring... does not reveal any new language options).  Perhaps I need to install the file somewhere else since I am using Xcode 5, but I am having trouble finding any info on this since Pascal is not very popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://tungchingkai.blogspot.ca/2012/08/pascal-for-xcode-4.html

Basically, you need to run the script on that from the Terminal, and that will add the Pascal "syntax coloring".